# change image of phone on emulator

Tags: android

I need to make a screencast of an app to present to a client, but need it to look better than the ugly red phone or the various other incarnations of the emulator.  Is there a way to swap out that image?

Also would be great to get rid of the keyboard that displays next to it and make the window borders go way (since I have to capture it full screen on a mac, unfortunately, I can't crop it tight).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an AVD, you can specify a different skin to use.  Besides the ones available by default, there are also a bunch on the web for various devices.  You can search for "[phone name] emulator skin" to find a variety, but here are a couple of examples:

- [Nexus One](http://blog.mathiaslin.com/nexus-one-emulator-skin-updated)
- [Nexus S](http://www.androidacademy.com/3-tutorials/43-hands-on/237-nexus-s-emulator-skin)

Answer (score 0):

The Motorola MOTODEV site (http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/tools/) has addons for nearly every one of our released phones. Registration is required.  Most of the addons are full system images, which should work or you could extract out the skin for your own uses.  There is a "skin only" addon for the upcoming XOOM tablet that uses Gingerbread for the runtime.

Good luck